# Logstash new field from other field with regex

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

From string

```
""message" => "27.03.2018 07:53:39 [ERROR] at MyApp.Controllers.Controller.OnException: \nMessage: Controller exception!\nUser: TestUser  \nHost: MyLaptop\n\nSystem.Exception: Testing\n   at MyApp.Controllers.DoController.Do() in C:\\Users\\User\\Source\\Controllers\\DoController.cs:line 20\n   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )\n   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)\n""
```

I am trying to match the "\n User \n" and put it into new field called User. With gsub I can mutate it fine with the following conf:

```
        mutate {
            gsub => [
                "message", "[\n]^User.*\n", "changed"
            ]
        }
```

But putting that into grok results in grokparsefailure. How can I use that in grok?

Comment: I've got a problem with the `^`. How can you match anything since the User is not at the start of the string?

Comment: Uhm, I do not know why it works. I just know that it works in the gsub since the string is changed correctly with that. it just does not work with grok match. Do you have suggestions what kind of the regex should be like instead?

Comment: To grab `TestUser` from your example, I'd use `\\nUser: %{USER:user}`. You can use http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match to test your grok patterns.

Comment: User in this case could be made of two or three words. Does that pattern hit those cases as well? Also I tried that in the grok filter but still got parse failure:

   grok {
    match => {
     "user" => "\\nUser: %{USER:user}"
    }
   }

Comment: If you want to grab multi-word User, you can use `\\nUser: %{DATA:user}  \\n`. Your grok filter has an invalid configuration: you should use : `grok {
    match => { "message" => "\\nUser: %{DATA:user}  \\n" }
  }`

Comment: Have I understood it completely wrong that the "message" is not the field where I want to put the matched data?

Comment: "message" is the field on which the grok filter is used. The field where the matched data is put is indicated in the pattern. In `\\nUser: %{DATA:user} \\n`, it will create a field called `user`. Try the pattern with your example in http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match, it should help you understand how it works.

Comment: It looks that I am still getting grokparsefailure with that latest configuration. Is grok failing because the user line could look like this:
\nUser: User test ((fail))\n

Comment: With more testing and reading documentation I ended up with:
   grok { 
    match => { 
     "message" => "User:%{GREEDYDATA:user}\n" 
    } 
   }

This seems to be working like it should and now I can proceed with my logstash configuration.

Comment: Ok, good luck for the rest!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with:

```
grok { 
     match => { 
        "message" => "User:%{GREEDYDATA:user}\n" 
     } 
}
```

This seems to be matching everything between `"User:"` and `"\n"`

Answer (score 0):

There you go,

```
User:%{SPACE}%{WORD:user}
```

this will create a new field `user` with the username,

```
{
  "SPACE": [
    [
      " "
    ]
  ],
  "user": [
    [
      "TestUser"
    ]
  ]
}
```